# Predicted values from a log model using add_predictions() are a long way off

Tags: r, ggplot2, logging, lm

I've fit a log model to some data, which works nicely:

```
model_data <- structure(list(standard_conc_ngul = c(50, 50, 50, 5, 5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005), ct = c(18.3305377960205, 
18.133768081665, 17.8813705444336, 21.5002365112305, 21.4915542602539, 
22.7616996765137, 23.6836719512939, 25.3699340820312, 25.3488445281982, 
28.984302520752, 26.7397594451904, 27.8844776153564)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> print(model_data)
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   standard_conc_ngul    ct
                <dbl> <dbl>
 1             50      18.3
 2             50      18.1
 3             50      17.9
 4              5      21.5
 5              5      21.5
 6              0.5    22.8
 7              0.5    23.7
 8              0.05   25.4
 9              0.05   25.3
10              0.005  29.0
11              0.005  26.7
12              0.005  27.9

model <- lm(log(standard_conc_ngul) ~ ct, data = model_data)
> summary(model)$r.squared
[1] 0.9727793 

ggplot(model_data, aes(x = standard_conc_ngul, y = ct)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ log(x)) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ log(x),
               aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), after_stat(rr.label), sep = "~~~")),
               parse = TRUE, coef.digits = 3, f.digits = 3, p.digits = 3, 
               rr.digits = 3)
```

[image]

I'd now like to use this model to predict `standard_conc_ngul` from `ct` in new data. Before I do that I wanted to test the predictions in the same model data above. However, when I do it they're nowhere near:

```
library(modelr)
model_data %>%
  add_predictions(model, var = "standard_conc_ngul_predicted") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = standard_conc_ngul, y = standard_conc_ngul_predicted)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Any idea what's going on??

Answer (score 2):

The predictions are calculating the natural log of your outcome to match the equation. Correcting them using `exp` gives comparable values:

```r
library(tidyverse)

model_data %>%
  modelr::add_predictions(model, var = "standard_conc_ngul_predicted") |> 
  mutate(pred = exp(standard_conc_ngul_predicted)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = standard_conc_ngul, y = pred)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Is this what you're looking for?